# My Minecraft Resource Packs I downloaded and made won't show up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I've made three resource packs from the same template. They are all in my resource packs folder, but only one shows up in the menu. One of the two that don't show up used to show up, the other I just completed and I have never been able to test. After scouring the internet for about an hour and try every fix i could find, nothing has changed. So I decided to ask my own question. And no it's not zipped, but I run Sphax unzipped just fine, and my other resource packs work fine unzipped, so no, that won't help.

Comment: You say it won't help but have you actually tried using the zipped versions?

Comment: yes but it did not help.

Comment: You have created a valid pack.mcmeta file in the root directory right? You can copy one from here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack

Answer (score 4):

I'm here because I was having a very similar problem. I've just managed to solve it, and I figured, even if this question is a bit old by now, maybe something I did will be helpful for you, or for whomever comes along next.

I was trying to mix and match some textures from my favorite resource packs. I found that, when I tried to modify the pack description in pack.mcmeta (the text after `description:`), even the tiniest bit - like deleting a character and then putting it back - Minecraft was immediately unable to recognize my resource pack. Here's what I did:

- I went to `TextEdit` > `Preferences` > `Format`, then selected `Plain text` rather than `Rich text`.
- While I was there, just for good measure, unchecked `Add '.txt' extension to plain text files` in the `Open and Save` options.
- And this took me forever to notice, but whenever I altered the pack description, the quotation marks around it auto-corrected to their slanted versions. Apparently, it's super important that they remain regular vertical quotation marks. When I finished editing my description, I just copied and pasted in vertical quotes before saving the file.

Some other info: I'm on OS-X Sierra, using Minecraft 1.10, pack format 2

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a difference if they are Zipped or not.  When you open the Zipped/unzipped folder you should see another folder named aspects.  If you don't see that I think I found you're problem...  You Just move the Folder that contains the aspects folder to your resourcepacks folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the folder structure isn't:
    RPN/RPN/assets/...
instead of
    RPN/assets/...
Note: RPN stands for Resource Pack Name.

When zipping on a mac, select the assets folder and pack.mcmeta to compress, not the folder containing those files

Also check to make sure your resource packs contain a pack.mcmeta file

Comment: I tried that and it did not work also, for me sphax is just rpn/assets.

Answer (score 0):

Do your resource packs contain a pack.mcmeta file? This is a necessary file in resource packs which makes them able to be detected by Minecraft.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question...